# What do I need to write Java-based web applications and test them on my personal computer?

Tags: java

I currently have Apache HTTP Server, but I'm guessing I'll need Tomcat (and then have to configure it in a way that makes it not open to the public), a Java JDK (which I already have, but should probably update), and an IDE (I have Eclipse). But what else should I have or know before starting?

Comment: @ThomasOwens: H2 or DB40 might be options re: databases. H2 supercedes HSQLDB, and DB4O is a OODBMS which eases the issues of object-relational mappings. Both are implemented in Java, and H2 is fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets see... you'll need:

1. A JDK.  Preferably the [Standard Edition](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp), unless you plan on using GlassFish as a J2EE server.  If you do use the standard edition, you need to include the jars from your servlet container/J2EE stack to access J2EE libraries.
2. A Servlet container.  [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) is a popular one, and Eclipse already has integration support for it.  Keep in mind that Tomcat is not a complete J2EE stack... you need something like [JBoss Application Server](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/) or [Apache Geronimo](http://geronimo.apache.org/) for that.
3. (Semi-Optional) A web server.  Apache Web Server *surprisingly* works well with Apache Tomcat or Apache Geronimo... it's almost like they were made by the same people!  Eclipse has built-in support for Tomcat and doesn't appear to require a web server because of it.  I could be wrong, though.
4. (Optional) An IDE.  If you use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), get the version for Java EE Developers.
5. (Optional) A Database.  MySQL and HSQLDB are popular ones for Java, at least for small to medium applications.  Keep in mind that you also need to download the JDBC drivers for your database.
6. (Optional) A revision control system.  Even on a single-developer project, a revision control system can save your hide if you accidentally remove code or a file that you shouldn't.  There are several choices here;  [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) is my personal choice, along with an Eclipse plugin for it, such as [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend having a database server installed as well- you can go pretty far with the various pure Java implementations, but anything significant will probably benefit from having a copy of MySQL around.

I'd also get some sort of version control going- tortoiseSVN works really well for windows. Even if you're just goofing around for yourself, getting in the habit of using it will save time and heartache down the road.

Comment: Yes. I have MySQL installed as I've done PHP development before, and I use TortoiseSVN, but still good advice for other people who don't have these installed.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to stay pretty simple you have everything you need; a servlet container.

The IDE of course helps.

I would recommend Eclipse's Web tools project as it will allow you to code, and then hit a button that will put that code on tomcat all from the IDE.

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

As Bogdan mentioned maven is a dependency management tool but depending on your level of comfort I'm not sure if you want to muddy the water with that yet.

Another project that uses Maven is appfuse (http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) and will help you get off the ground quickly for generating a webapp. It will give you a webapp, a database, unit tests, dependency management, and a good skeleton to structure your project off of.

So, if you're just wanting to play around with some .jsps and a servlet or two I would stick with the IDE, but if you're comfortable with web applications, MVC, and build tools I'd recommend appfuse.

Answer (score 1):

That's all you need from the tools.

Then, you need to google some tutorial on using servlets and jsp pages. Even documentation bundled with tomcat is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably also want a database like MySQL or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/). You could replace Tomcat with [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/) which is often easier to get class changes to reload without restarting the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything from within NetBeans if you're willing to switch IDEs (it's a relatively painless switch, but you might be able to create a similar setup in Eclipse).  There's a Tomcat plugin for NetBeans that allows you to create, edit, run, and debug servlet and JSP web apps all from within NetBeans.  There's a starter tutorial [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetbeansedTomcat).  When you install the Tomcat plugin, you get lots of good example servlets and JSPs as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for maven.

It will give you a quick start in configuring your project (by using archetypes) and it will manage your dependencies.

Install it and run the archetype command to create your project.

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

After that just use the maven eclipse plugin to configure your eclipse environment for that project (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/).

Comment: Hmmmm... somebody doesn't like dependency management and automatic environment configuration. Pity,it saves a lot of time, especially automatic IDE configuration.

Answer (score 0):

*I currently have Apache HTTP Server, but I'm guessing I'll need Tomcat (and then have to configure it in a way that makes it not open to the public)*

> For simple Java based web applications, you need not have Apache installed unless you are too concerned about performance and want to gain by letting Apache serve static resources.

*But what else should I have or know before starting?*

> A good IDE is most recommended, otherwise the development will become painful. Use a simple database as people have already suggested. I would go with MySQL because its neither too complex for a webapp nor too trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Tomcat I recommend [Jetty](http://jetty.org/), that is also a Servlet-Container. In my experience it's easier to setup and maintain. Good enough to test your application.

Other than that you need a JDK (naturally). A database is optional, but if your web-app wants to save data it's the best option.

Comment: Tomcat is a servlet container :)

Comment: Now I said, that Jetty IS a servlet-container. Better?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:you need to have J2EE installed in your system if not download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html here.

Step 2: Should have Apache TomCat server to run your web project on your system locally(local Server).
installation steps https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html go to this website.

Step 3:set Class path for java JRE.